# How do I write "raw" bytes to the browser in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am trying to serve a PDF file to the user, and I have a string containing the bytes in the PDF file. I want to write these bytes to the browser so the user can download the PDF file. However when I do this:

```
document.open('application/pdf');
document.write(myBytes);
```

I just get the bytes rendered as text, that is, they are in an HTML page (see screenshots). I want only the bytes specified to be rendered, without any HTML surrounding them. How can I do this?

[image: PDF bytes rendered in an HTML page]

[image: HTML source of my "PDF"]

[image]

Comment: The DOM tree is not the best place to inspect raw output. What do "Network/ Response" or "View/ Source" menu items show?

Comment: "View source" gives me the HTML for the page that I navigated from to get to the PDF; I suppose this is because I did the rewriting of the page in JavaScript so the source never actually got updated. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "network/response", but I'll go ahead and attach some screenshots from the network tab in the browser dev tools.

Comment: You've shared the "Headers" secondary tab in the "Network" tab. "Response" is close to it (it's the fourth tab in Firefox). You're getting HTML because that's exactly what `document` represents, an HTML document—but PDF is not HTML. See Józef's answer for a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force file download with `anchor` && `download` attribute trick or use `iframe`

**Here's an example below**

Snippet doesn't work because of sandboxed environment.

```js
const pdfView = document.querySelector("#pdfView");

fetch("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf")
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => blob.arrayBuffer())
  .then(myBytes => {
    const totalBlob = new Blob([myBytes], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(totalBlob);
    const anchor = document.createElement("a");
    anchor.href = url;
    anchor.download = `document.pdf`;
    anchor.click();
    anchor.textContent = 'Download'
    document.body.appendChild(anchor);

    pdfView.src = url;  
  })
```

```html
<iframe id="pdfView" src="" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%" style="overflow: auto;">
    </iframe>
```

Comment: Hmm... But the PDF I have is not accessible via a URL; it's just a string containing a bunch of bytes. If I were to make it accessible via a URL I'd have to worry about assigning it the right permissions so no one can go in and punch in a URL to look at someone else's PDF.

Comment: You can use code what is inside `then(myBytes => {` function in this case

Comment: @ekolis `fetch()` is only used to provide a runnable self-contained example, the key point is creating a `Blob` and generating a data URI for it.

Comment: Thanks! So now I have a five page blank PDF being downloaded, now to figure out why it's blank...